# Design a SCNNode in Xcode’s IB

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, scenekit

I’m trying to design a single SCNNode that consists of text, rectangles, etc. I can do this via code, however, I was wondering if there’s an IB approach to it. Something like designing a table row cell in IB.

Is there a way to design a SCNNode’s view in the IB?

Note: I’m not trying to design the entire scene, just a node.

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder is limited to designing complete scenes, but you can build a scene with a single node and then load that node from the scene programmatically:

```
    let sceneWithOneNode = SCNScene(named: "OneNode.scn")
    let myNode = humonshipScene?.rootNode.childNodes[0]
```

Alternatively, your scene can contain multiple nodes which you can assign by name (if you gave them names in the scene)

```
let sceneWithOneNode = SCNScene(named: "OneNode.scn")
let myNode = menuScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "hud", recursively: true)!
```

Comment: That's an interesting hack. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: It's actually the supported way to do it.

Comment: Did it work for you? If so, could you mark it as an answer?

Comment: Naa, it didn't work for me. I ended up writing it in code.